# dpkg returned an error code(2)

Tags: apt

```
#computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ sudo apt-get install 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 libllvm2.9 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.11) but it is not installed 
              Depends: libffi6 (>= 3.0.4) but it is not installed 
              Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installed 
              Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but it is not installed 
              PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.# 
##computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following extra packages will be installed: 
  apt-utils coreutils debconf debconf-i18n dpkg gcc-4.6-base libacl1 
  libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc6 libdb5.1 
  libffi6 libgcc1 liblocale-gettext-perl liblzma5 libselinux1 libstdc++6 
  libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl 
  multiarch-support perl-base tar tzdata xz-utils zlib1g 
Suggested packages: 
  debconf-doc debconf-utils whiptail dialog gnome-utils 
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libgtk2-perl libnet-ldap-perl libqtgui4-perl 
  libqtcore4-perl apt glibc-doc locales bzip2 ncompress xz-lzma 
The following NEW packages will be installed: 
  apt-utils coreutils debconf debconf-i18n dpkg gcc-4.6-base libacl1 
  libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc6 libdb5.1 
  libffi6 libgcc1 liblocale-gettext-perl liblzma5 libselinux1 libstdc++6 
  libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtext-wrapi18n-perl 
  multiarch-support perl-base tar tzdata xz-utils zlib1g 
0 upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/14.4 MB of archives. 
After this operation, 42.9 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed? 
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory 
dpkg: error: syntax error in triggers deferred file `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp' at character `T' midline 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2) ##  

computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ cd/var/lib/dpkg/available 
bash: cd/var/lib/dpkg/available: No such file or directory 
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ cd/var/lib/dpkg/status 
bash: cd/var/lib/dpkg/status: No such file or directory 
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ cd/var/lib/dpkg/diversions 
bash: cd/var/lib/dpkg/diversions: No such file or directory 
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ ls -1 
adun 
brasero-session.log 
Calibre Library 
C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt 
Desktop 
Documents 
Downloads 
examples.desktop 
GNUstep 
Music 
Pictures 
Public 
Templates 
Ubuntu One 
Untitled Document 
Videos 
win7-uninstall.tar.gz 
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$
```

Comment: Could you offer more details? Like, what was the command that lead to the error?

Comment: computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ sudo apt-get update      
Reading package lists... Done     
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ sudo apt-get install  
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed? debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory 
dpkg: error: syntax error in triggers deferred file `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp' at character `T' midline 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: Could you edit the question itself and add that.

Comment: You had entered `sudo apt-get install`. That should be followed by a package name. `sudo apt-get install [PACKAGE NAME]`. In your edit , you should have make a space between `cd`and `/var/lib/dpkg/available`. In terminal you should have entered `cd /var/lib/dpkg/available`. (not `cd/var/lib/dpkg/available`)

Comment: Or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before trying to run any installs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done anything recently that might have messed up `dpkg`?

Try the check if `available`, `status` and `diversions` have 0 file size.

Do this by :

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/
ls -l
```

**Sample output:**

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 13 2008 alternatives
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 0 Jun 3 13:46 available
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 99608 Jun 28 2008 available-old
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 0 Jun 3 13:46 diversions
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 2501 Feb 28 2008 diversions-old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 32768 Apr 13 2008 info
```

If the file size is 0, issue the following commands:

```
sudo cp available-old available
sudo cp diversions-old diversions
sudo cp status-old status
```

Then try to issue your `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ cd/var/lib/dpkg/available 
bash: cd/var/lib/dpkg/available: No such file or directory 
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ cd/var/lib/dpkg/status 
bash: cd/var/lib/dpkg/status: No such file or directory 
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ cd/var/lib/dpkg/diversions 
bash: cd/var/lib/dpkg/diversions: No such file or directory 
computer@computer-Satellite-L755:~$ ls -1 
adun 
brasero-session.log 
Calibre Library 
C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt 
Desktop 
Documents 
Downloads 
examples.desktop 
GNUstep 
Music 
Pictures 
Public 
Templates 
Ubuntu One

Comment: @user224764 please edit your question instead. Comments are not the place to add new information

Comment: @user224764 there is a space character between `cd` and `/`. Copy and paste the exact commands.